# PyCharm: how to properly quote arguments for debugging?

Tags: debugging, pycharm, arguments, quoting

I need to pass a short JSON fragment as argument for my program:

```
python3 myscript.py --json '{"TP":"COR10","PR":55,"TM":607781280,"RP":[{"AMM":21.31,"IVA":22.00,"IMP":4.69}]}'
```

This seems to work from the command line, but if inserted verbatim into `Edit Configurations` -> `Parameters` quotes are preserved:

```
b"'{TP:COR10,PR:55,TM:607781280,RP:[{AMM:21.31,IVA:22.00,IMP:4.69}]}'"
```

I can understand it kept outermost single quotes because there's no `shell` to parse the arguments, but why did it remove double quotes?

In order to get desired result I need to leave out surronding single quotes *and* quote each and every "strange" char (including whitespace, not present in the example), as in:

```
--json {\"TP\":\"COR10\",\"PR\":55,\"TM\":607781280,\"RP\":[{\"AMM\":21.31,\"IVA\":22.00,\"IMP\":4.69}]}
```

This looks awkward to say the least.
Is there some shortcut I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

You tried with someoune like the second example but usign sigle quotes?

> --json {'TP':'COR10','PR':55,'TM':607781280,'RP':[{'AMM':21.31,'IVA':22.00,'IMP':4.69}]}

Is the same form the parser

Comment: That is *not* a valid JSON. Unlike Python, JSON does *not* allow single quotes.